# Disable dropshadow on Firefox 4 menu text etc

Tags: firefox

The following worked to disable the dropshadow with tabs in Firefox 4 by adding:

```
.tabbrowser-tab { text-shadow: none !important; }
```

to the userChrome.css file.

Does anyone know what I need to add to disable the dropshadow for the main file menu text and also the text in the download bar etc?

Comment: Have you checked this - http://www.wikihow.com/Custom-Colorize-Firefox

Answer (score 0):

You failed to mention your operating system and any Firefox or system theme(s) you are using. Unfortunately, I cannot confirm any text drop-shadow as you described. I am using Windows 7 and the Aero theme:

[image: screenshot]

### But...

If you wanted to style the `text-shadow` property on tab labels, menu item labels, and download labels, the following CSS selectors will work:

```
label.tab-label,
label.menu-iconic-text,
label.menu-text,
label.menubar-text,
label.name
{
    text-shadow: none !important;
}
```